# Expression for Covariance- summation over duplicates

Tags: covariance

Suppose I have a random variable:
$$
Y_{it}=A_{it}+B_{it}
$$
 which is made up of two random variables $A$ and $B.$ $i$ is the
unit of observation that runs through $i=1....N$ for each time period $t=1...T$. Now taking the
covariance of $Y$ for any two units $i$ and $j$ **over time**, we have:
$$
cov(Y_{i},Y_{j})=cov(A_{i},A_{j})+cov(B_{i},B_{j})+cov(A_{i},B_{j})+cov(A_{j},B_{i})
$$
Now, I want to figure out the average contribution of the term $cov(A_{i},A_{j})$
to the term $cov(Y_{i},Y_{J}).$ What I have is 
$$
C=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{cov(A_{i},A_{j})}{cov(Y_{i},Y_{j})}
$$

Notice that the variance-covariance matrix is symmetric. As such, there are ionly $N/(N-1)/2$ unique entries ($cov(A_{1},A_{_2}$)=$cov(A_{2},A_{1})$. I know that the expression above is incorrect (as it generates duplicates). How can I modify the above expression to correct notation such that it contains only a unique occurence of symmetric covariances?

Comment: Assuming that the only duplicates are of the form $\mathrm{Cov}(A_i,A_j) = \mathrm{Cov}(A_j,A_2)$ you could simply rewrite the summation as $$\frac{1}{\binom{n}{2} +n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^N\sum\limits_{j=i}^N \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(A_i,A_j) }{\mathrm{Cov}(Y_i,Y_j) }.$$

Comment: Why does the duplication of entries make it incorrect?

Comment: @herb It doesn't make it incorrect, but I am simply not considering them.

Comment: @herbsteinberg . In your expression, the summation still is over all N for i and j. How will this ignore duplicates?

Comment: @ChinG Why ignore duplicates?  The only thing to be careful of is the treatment of those terms where i=j.

Comment: $Cov(A_i,A_i)$ has to be treated differently from $Cov(A_i,A_j)$ where $i\ne j$.  To get the average, you need to divide by $N$ for the terms where $i=j$ and divide by $N(N-1)$ for the others.  Combining these averages is dependent on what you mean by average.